# Academic Interview: What is your Greatest Weakness?

Tags: job, interview

A common interview question is "What is your greatest weakness?". Having done some online research on this, there are lots of articles on how to tackle this with generic job interviews, and the idea is to turn a negative into a positive. Some examples have been: "I'm not great at public speaking, but have been attending evening classes to improve", "I have trouble managing my work-life balance, but have recently been working on a more careful personalised timetable", and "I have not been great with deadlines, but I now give myself a personal deadline of 24 hours in advance".

However, academic interviews are often very specific, and focus on research, publications, collaborations, outreach, teaching etc. What are some examples of how to answer this question well, which are specific to academic interviews (e.g. for a postdoc / lectureship / professorship)?

Comment: "I'm working on improving my public speaking skills by ..." can be a great answer. Being able to identify a weakness shows humility and self-awareness, doing something about it is important, plus they have seen or will soon see your public speaking skills when you do your interview talk, so they either already know you need to work on this or will think if that's your greatest weakness, you don't have many weaknesses!

Comment: Does anyone actually ask this question in academic interviews?  There are many different departments/universities/countries out there, so I can't guarantee anything, but I've never seen this question asked to a job candidate, or even heard of anyone being asked it elsewhere.  Unless you have some specific reason to think you are likely to be asked this, I wouldn't worry about it or bother preparing for it.  I think it's very unlikely to come up, and even if someone did ask you I'd bet their colleagues wouldn't take the question or answer seriously.

Comment: I agree with @AnonymousMathematician - this isn't a likely question for you to be asked.

Comment: FYI, I agree with Anon. Math.s comment, but if it did come up, I would hate an answer like "I work too much."  (I also hate that question, so generally wouldn't pay much attention to such answers, but such an blatant show-offy answer would turn me off more.  The other example answers you give are fine.)

Comment: "I'm willing to take stupid interview questions like that one seriously." or "Kryptonite".

Comment: "My *greatest* weakness, you ask? [stare affectionately into the interviewer's eyes] Beautiful {interviewer's eye color} eyes."

Comment: "My greatest strength is that I have no weaknesses. My greatest weakness is that I have no strengths."

Comment: "Bears." - but in all seriousness, so long as you *don't* say you're a perfectionist which is the common answer, you'll be fine.

Comment: "A distaste for that overused question. Seriously, it's begging for the standard response of the interviewee trying to describe a strength as a failure, and that doesn't tell us much except whether they rehearsed for the interview."

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician I was asked at least twice.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician unfortunately, I've been asked this in 2 out of 3 academic interviews. Last time, it was actually, "what are your three biggest weaknesses?"

Comment: You: "Honesty." Them: "I don't think that's a weakness." You: "I don't give a damn what you think."

Comment: Not to be taken seriously, but here is one way out: http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=3407#comic

Comment: An approach I have used (but not in academia, so I'm not posting this as an answer) is to note that often people's greatest weakness and greatest strength is actually the same thing.  The "I work too much" line is a simple example of this.  What I like about that approach is that something that is both a strength and a weakness is almost always a deeply-embedded character trait.  I think letting an interviewer know about your character traits is a good thing, no matter what the question is.

Comment: for tenure-track this question is never asked, but in industry they ask you. it is related to you experience and knowledge not to you personally.

Comment: I am curious as to how it would go if answered with a invisible disability -- say depression or another mental illness. For a great many people there mental illnesses are their greatest weaknesses; and they also put your in a protected class. In most western countries you are not allowed to not hire someone because of a disability. Thus the interviewer not only learned nothing useful; they have infact learned something that leaves them more open to a potential law suit if the person it not hired. I've heard of interviewers not wanting to know about this kinda thing, to avoid legal issue

Comment: SE veteran @Kate Gregory blogged about this a while ago. Her answer is to see this question as an offer for training, mentoring, other ways in which the employer can accommodate you. http://www.gregcons.com/KateBlog/TheTrickQuestionInTheJobInterview.aspx

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**I would answer it as recommended.**  The best strategy is probably to admit a real weakness that is relevant to the work (which shows honesty and the ability to be self-critical), but focus on how you are working to improve.  There's nothing really academia-specific about this.

Your examples seem largely fine to me, except "I have trouble managing my work-life balance" is too vague and could be interpreted as a very serious issue.  So I would avoid that or make it more specific.

I wouldn't spend too much time preparing for this question. Its reputation as a common interview question is greater than the reality. I've never been asked it (at interviews in and out of academia).

It's a poor interview question, really, because it's unlikely to lead to genuine insight on the candidate. Good interviewers don't ask it. Your main task is just to avoid a big mistake. Don't say your biggest weakness is plagiarism or stabbing colleagues in the back, and you'll be fine.

Comment: I've never seen this particular question either, but I have seen many poor interview questions.  (Well after one SLAC interview I commented to that department's chair that I didn't see how you could learn very much from those questions, and the chair agreed with me.)

Comment: It's a *great* interview question *because* some candidates make a big  mistake.

Comment: @djechlin many people might mess up and give a dumb answer.  All that proves is that they aren't a perfectly polished interviewee.  But it's going to be a very rare candidate that inadvertently reveals a major weakness you wouldn't otherwise discover.

Comment: @dan1111: to the extent that it's a trap question, the secret weakness that it's hoping to reveal is "I am hopelessly un-self-critical". The candidate inadvertently reveals this by trying to blag perfectionism or working too hard as their greatest weakness. It's such a cliché that like you I question how many people will fall for it, but my partner interviews a lot and she has seen that kind of behaviour in interviewees. She doesn't use "what's your greatest weakness" AFAIK, though, she uses "give an example of a problem you've faced and how you overcame it" sort of thing.

Comment: @SteveJessop but it doesn't *really* reveal whether they are self-critical, only whether they think it is ok to admit that in an interview.  Because it is an obvious "gotcha" question, it invites calculated answers rather than honest communication, and you only end up measuring how adept of an interviewee the candidate is.

Comment: Well, I suppose at the very least you identify candidates whose greatest weakness is that they think an interview is a series of lies or defensive half-truths told to specification ;-) I'm not saying it's a good question, I don't think it is, but in fact it *does* reveal some weaknesses. True, by un-self-critical I meant unwilling to discuss it, not necessarily that they're deluded.

Comment: My greatest weakness is a vulnerability to kryptonite.

Comment: It's really not that rare though...

Comment: The first time I made interviews for PhD and postdoc positions, I made this question, as I had absolutely no experience in interviewing so I mostly looked up typical questions online. But I concluded it was worthless, mostly for the reasons @dan1111 mentions, so I don't make it anymore.

Answer (score 8):

I have been asked this question in interviews and have asked it during interviews. I actually think the question is pretty informative for academic positions. When I am reviewing a CV prior to an interview, I have thoughts about the strengths and weaknesses of the candidate. The CV provides information about areas the candidate is going to need to work on to get a promotion to the next level (e.g., a tenure track position or tenure).

It is a bad sign if the candidate answers with an area that is either unimportant for the job (e.g., publication record for a teaching position) or not an obvious weakness. This suggests to me that the candidate does not understand the position they are applying for and what needs to be done to get a promotion. Further, it makes me worried that if they do not see something as a weakness, that they will be less willing to accept criticism regarding it.

If a candidate simply blows off the answer (e.g., *I am really bad at golf*), then the interviewer learns that the candidate does not want to critically assess their strength and weaknesses. Again this is a bad sign.

If the candidate answers with a weakness, this is a good sign. The best, however, is if a candidate and can answer with a strength and talk about how this strength can be used to address a weakness. For example, a candidate with a strong funding record and a weak publication record might answer with *my greatest weakness is my success obtaining funding which has slowed my publication rate*. For a teaching oriented position, a candidate with a strong publication record but limited teaching might answer with *my greatest weakness was succumbing to pressure by my supervisor to publish and ignoring my desire to teach*.

Comment: Your "best" answers seem to be more along the lines of *"my greatest weakness is that the cards always seem to be stacked against me despite all my glory, but my strength is that I always persevere"*. I agree it sounds good, but really, are we talking about weaknesses at all here?

Comment: This seems backwards. If it's a teaching position, isn't it **better** (all things being equal) if their greatest weakness is their publication record?

Comment: The responses you get illustrate why this is a bad question. People don't understand what you want because you asked a broad, ambiguous question instead of clearly communicating what you want to know. In addition because it is such a negative question, people treat it as a bullet to be dodged and may feel it is a tactical mistake to admit a real relevant weakness. Why not ask something like "what area do you most need to develop in order to excel in this post?" rather than excluding possibly great candidates who couldn't guess your intent?

Comment: Yeah, it's a crapshoot. StrongBad wants you to say "my greatest weakness is my success obtaining funding which has slowed my publication rate", whereas other people would see that as a profoundly dishonest spin, and if you're going to use that example would want you to say "my greatest weakness is that while I'm pursuing funding I tend to let my publication rate slip". It's one thing to get your excuse in there, it's another thing to be pathologically unable to say "here is something I do wrong".

Comment: @TomChurch: but the candidate in the teaching role has acknowledged their big problem (teaching experience), explained why it happened, emphasises their *desire* to fix it, and hints that in the new role they could overcome it. Yes, all else being equal it would be better if they had more teaching experience applying for a teaching role, but their record is what it is. Given that record, if they ignore the weakness relevant to the role, and say they're bad at publishing or bad at making coffee, they've declined an opportunity to mitigate the weakness that the interviewer is worried about.

Comment: That said, if the interviewer already knows what the candidate's greatest weakness is from the POV of this role, then the more direct approach would be to say, "so what about your lack of teaching experience then?" rather than hoping to nudge the candidate into raising it themselves. Like StrongBad says though, there's some value in knowing whether the candidate is capable of assessing their greatest weakness in the context of the role they've chosen to apply for. So to some extent the question is, "do you understand why you're here today?"

Comment: +1 in general, until the very end.  "my greatest weakness is my success obtaining funding which has slowed my publication rate"  is an aggrandizing way of saying "my ability to prioritize needs some work".  There are much better ways to say this than blaming a failure on a success, which makes very little sense to me.  I would think its better to own the weakness, and create the case that you're dealing with this in a believable way.

Answer (score 2):

"What is your greatest weakness?" is a bad interview question. It's in the same category as "If you were an animal, what would you be, and why?", and the classic "Where do you see yourself in five years?".

In my opinion, these type of questions warrant a <s>dry, sarcastic</s> simple answer or just "I don't know". Your interviewer(s) won't learn anything important about you from such questions anyway.

But whatever you do, please don't tell you interviewer(s) things like "I have trouble managing my work-life balance" or "I have not been great with deadlines", even if you plan to try to somehow turn these into positives. I've seen candidates dropped for less. As a student (at the very least) you've had many years to learn how to manage your work-life balance and how to deal with deadlines, and you really have no excuse as to why you can't yet do these things at a sufficiently good level.

Comment: This is bad advice.  While it is a poor question, "I don't know" is an even worse answer.  The fact that the interviewer asked it means they think it is important, and therefore you ought to take it seriously.  This means having a real answer about a personal weakness.  I'm not as worried as you are about the examples the OP gave, but if one is, one could respond with something that is more minor or more in the past.

Comment: @dan1111 "The fact that the interviewer asked it means they think it is important". That's generally not the case. Most often, such questions are asked by HR people, who either have some sort of a check list, or have been trained to ask such questions, or simply think these questions are okay, because they are so popular. In any case, they don't really think it's an imporant question, and besides, "I don't know" is a perfectly valid answer, especially in academia.

Comment: I agree that "I don't know" can be the right answer in interviews.  But as an answer to this particular question it will come across either as a serious lack of self-awareness or a refusal to respond.  Neither is good.  Also, I think an interviewee should assume that the interviewers care about the questions they are asking.  Assuming that it is an HR-dictated question that nobody cares about is a bad idea.  And even if true, candidates who take the question seriously will come across better than you.

Comment: @dan1111 "a serious lack of self-awareness" Not at all. "What is your greatest weakness?" is vague at best. Weakness in what sense? What conditions? Maybe my weakness is not a single weakness, but a combination of traits. Maybe my weakness doesn't allow me to identify it. Maybe it's something I'm not comfortable talking about. A serious answer would take a considerable amount of effort. And since the interviewer doesn't expect such a serious answer, I can only think that they were not serious when asking the question. So my answer to a non-serious question would be a non-serious answer.

Comment: The correct response to a vague question is asking for clarification.  The correct response to not being comfortable talking about something is saying so (though, this question is hardly "out of bounds" as many personal strengths and weaknesses are highly relevant to your job performance).

Comment: @101010111100 I have never in my life been interviewed by HR people for an academic post (many hiring committees contain HR staff which sit in the meetings etc, but in my experience never as decision makers, only as observers of correct process).

Comment: @xLeitix My experience as well. Except that the HR person typically asks a couple of questions, as if to acknowledge their presence.

Comment: @101010111100 And those questions are usually either entirely administrative or have been planted on them by the academics on the panel.

Comment: Yeah, I would *not* assume the question is "asked by HR people". Both times I've been asked about it, it's been from someone with "Dr." in front of their name.

Comment: @dan1111: Regarding "out of bounds", I wonder how many people would have the brass nose to answer, "my greatest weakness is something that for reasons of employment discrimination I am entitled not to discuss in this interview and you are not permitted to take into account in your hiring decision even if I did. Next question" :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have been asked this in an interview for a lectureship in pure mathematics. At the time I was quite junior so I just said that I didn't much have much administrative experience. They then just moved on.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should interpret it as: *Name a personal weakness related to the position you are applying to*.

The point is to see (a) whether you have insight into your relative strengths and weaknesses, and (b) whether you have a plan of using your strengths to get around those weaknesses.

It's normal and expected that you will do (and enjoy) some parts of your job better than others, and you need to reassure the hiring committee that you won't get stuck on the parts that aren't your favorite.