# Point of weakness for tenure track postions

Tags: job-search, tenure-track

What is the greatest weakness point Question? I want to be honest when answering this question. Actually, I have a problem which speaking so fast in English (which is not my first language). So, I would like to answer this question as" Some times I became so enthusiastic and speak so fast in English" and to handle this issue" I always ask student feedback to keep my self speaking slowly.

Is this answers hurts me?

I know there are "ideal" answers on the internet such as pointed here [1](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/75005/academic-interview-what-is-your-greatest-weakness)

Comment: My greatest weakness is that I’ve never been asked that question.

Comment: My greatest strength is that I've never asked that question.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that your actual answer doesn't matter that much.

These "open" questions are often asked, in my experience, to get you to talk. Unless the content of your answer raises a big red flag, the relevant part will be how you react to it, how you pose your answer, etc. It's a "starter", depending on your answer you might get interesting follow-ups that lead to somewhere interesting, or maybe just move on with the conversation.

Don't try to force it back to your pre-defined talking points, and never push shop talk during social events, like during the meals with the committee. If they steer the conversation that way, sure, but be yourself, with more interests than research/teaching, etc...

Beyond all else, don't overthink it. Nobody solid is going to get discarded over this (again, except red flags), and nobody "unprepared" will get picked because of this. Use your energy to be very sharp on your teaching statement, research ideas, etc. That's what actually makes a difference.